# How to convert arrayofstring to any type of collections

Tags: java, collections

I implemented a C # web service that works very well for consumption, I created a client in Java, so far everything worked well, until I meet a cast of problem on the return of the method. Indeed my method is supposed to send me a list, but I can not convert it back to a different kind of collection.
Here is my code:

C # Service:

```
[WebMethod]


  public List <string> AfficherTous ()
    {/ / Return implementation}
```

Java client:

```
 Myservice sv = new Myservice ();
 List <String> sv = (List <String>) sv.getMonserviceSoap.AfficherTous ();
```

so I cast a mistake, but it works very well when the method return only a thong.

Comment: Can you try a little change. For your c# code, change small string to capital String.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your service across platform. You can try by converting your list to String[] array here like this:

```
String[] myArray = list.ToArray();
```

so your c# service would look like this:

```
[WebMethod]

    public String[] AfficherTous()
    {
         // your implementation of List<String> creation

         return list.ToArray();
    }

**in java client:**

 Myservice sv = new Myservice ();
 String[] sv = (String[]) sv.getMonserviceSoap.AfficherTous (); // Line A
```

Now coming to basics, whenever an object is sent over the network you need to make sure that it is Serializable. Here your List class and String class are serialized as provided by Microsoft's library. Secondly, all data that is sent over network is in the byte form. On the receiving side, the byte data can be again be converted back to your class object like in **Line A** of the above snippet. However, I believe that the List class of java and C# differ in the byte representation, that caused your casting issue in the first place. But both String classes should almost be identical in the byte form.

You can also make use of JSON and XML formats for your work.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, the method returns a Arrayofstring and cast between this return and a String [] is not possible.

Comment: Firstly You should add comment instead of answering.